# Filter Criteria problem with condition

Tags: views

I have one view and need to filter from more than one content type and condition. But I can only use only one group, if I create more group, the content can not be selected.
[image: image for filter error]

please kindly answer my question.

Thank

Comment: "the content can not be selected" - Do you mean that you get zero results? Please clarify and possibly provide more detail.